# java. how can I let it click for as long as it finds it?

Tags: selenium

How can I let this click for as long as it finds the element?

```
driver.findElement(By.className("test")).click();
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for `.findElements()` ... this should give you a list of elements to loop over.

Comment: then this is the result Filburt: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGug8.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGug8.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a loop and check for it's existence, if it exists, click it:

```
while(driver.findElements(By.className("test")).size() != 0)
{
    driver.findElement(By.className("test")).click();
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if he meant that literally ("for as long as") but if he did, yours is the proper answer.

Comment: while(driver.findElements(By.className("test")).size() != 0)
       {
           click();
       }

Comment: So you literally want to click a button over and over until it disappears?  Strange.

Comment: @BillHileman I agree, I think for this you would at least want to delay the next click for x amount of time, clicking as fast as a CPU can loop would be asking for trouble in my opinion.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer since it does seem you gave him exactly what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Filburt's answer in the comments, use an if with .findElements like this:

```
if (!driver.findElements(By.className("test")).IsEmpty())
    driver.findElement(By.className("test")).click();
```